# Core Data and Multiple Persistant Stores

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I am using Core Data to save a bunch of information.

Lets say I have option for 3 different saves in a game. If the user selects SaveGame1, it loads SavedGameStore1. If the user selects SaveGame2, it loads SavedGamedStore2.

They all contain the same Entities.

I don't need to transfer information from one Store to another Store.

My understanding of the `Persistent Stores` and `Persistent Store Coordinator` is a bit shaky.

I am using Magical Record.

In the appDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [MagicalRecord setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack];
}
```

Magical Record has a method `setupCoreDataStackWithSotreNamed:`.

Is it as simple as after the user makes his selection, just call that method? That would switch it from the default store to my SavedGameStore1?

Comment: Why not just have `SavedGameStore` be an entity in your store on use only one `persistent store`? I would try my best to stay away from using multiple stores at ALL cost. Like you said, it is shaky.

Comment: Ok. I was thinking multiple stores would be better easier. Am I wrong about that?

Comment: In my experience using a single store is always easier and always more stable. I would suggest you stick with a single store based on your model above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be correct.  You'll want to (carefully) call [MagicalRecord cleanUp] to tear down the existing core data stack before loading in a new one with [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:].

I wonder if you can't put all the save game data into a single store?  Could you add an additional entity with relationships to the save game data?  This will likely simplify things...

Comment: I can put an additional entity easily enough. I guess in my thought process having a different store for each would be simpler/easier. Am i wrong about that?

Comment: IMO, it will almost always be easier/cleaner to use a single data store.